# resizable и draggable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Подскажите как лучше поступить
Есть изображения,подгруженные ajax в div id="imagebox",затем я могу выбрать нужные мне изображения

```
 $('body').on('click', 'img', function () {

        $(this).toggleClass('selimg');
    });
```

и после этого я могу выделенные изображения добавить в нужные мне блок

```
  $("#toimg").click(function () {

        var divid = $(".selected").attr("id");
        $('#' + divid).append($(".selimg"));
        $("img").removeClass("selimg");

    });
```

Вопрос:Как мне после добавления в нужный блок разрешить изображениям передвигаться и менять размер

```
  $("img").resizable({
    containment: "parent"
    });
    $('.ui-wrapper').draggable({
    containment: 'parent'
    });
```

Заранее большое спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте обернуть `img` в `div` и повесить  `resizable` и `draggable` на `div`